# how to dynamically load select option values using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am new to ajax. On check click of checkbox I want my select combo box field to load dynamically by ajax. what I want is when I click on check box ajax should fetch data from `two.jsp` file and populate that data in my select box in `one.jsp`

one.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
function go_here(){
    if(document.getElementById('c1').checked){
        var xRequest1;

        //if(string1=="")
        //{
        //document.getElementById("Offer_id").innerHTML="";
        //return;
        }
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
        xRequest1=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
        xRequest1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xRequest1.onreadystatechange=function ()
        {
        if((xRequest1.readyState==4) && (xRequest1.status==200))
        {
        document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML=xRequest1.responseText;
        }
        }

        xRequest1.open("get","two.jsp","true");

        xRequest1.send();    


    }
    else{

    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" onclick="go_here();"><br>
<select  name="Offer_id"  id='s1'  >

</select>
</body>
</html>
```

two.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <option value="5234">abc1</option>
    <option value="5235">abc2</option>
    <option value="4947">abc2</option>
    <option value="5210">abc2</option>
    <option value="5208">abc2</option>
    <option value="5209">abc2</option>
    <option value="3974">abc100</option>
</body>
</html>
```

but I am not able to populate my select box's option fields. can some one guide me where am I wrong..

Comment: I guess you should comment the bracket here:  //document.getElementById("Offer_id").innerHTML="";
        //return;        }

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to set the selects innerHTML to the responseText, you are trying to 'paste' the entire text describing the page two.jsp inside the select.

Apart from strongly disagreeing that you use a html document to transmit the option data instead of xml or json, you'll have either:

1) Parse the two.jsp page into a live html document and the use a selector to set the innerHTML of your select to the innerHTML of the body from the two.jsp document.

OR

2) cut the string from the responseText into pieces so that you only have the options left and use that string to set your selects innerhtml.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right way to do it. You need to change your two.jsp to return data (either XML or JSON) rather than an HTML page. Then your AJAX will fetch the data and loop through it to create & add the options to your control.

Alternatively, if you really want your two.jsp to be generating the HTML options for the control (although some people will consider this to be a bad design), you can create a function in the two.jsp to only return the required HTML. AJAX will fetch the HTML by calling that function and then will assign the HTML to the control's `innerHTML` property.

A quick fix can be by changing two.jsp to this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<option value="5234">abc1</option>
<option value="5235">abc2</option>
<option value="4947">abc2</option>
<option value="5210">abc2</option>
<option value="5208">abc2</option>
<option value="5209">abc2</option>
<option value="3974">abc100</option>
```